# How to return SOAPFault to the client from the Filter?

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, soap, servlet-filters

I have the code below and I need to return **SOAP response (correct XML)**. If I `throw new SoapException(...)`, it will return HTML page which is wrong. Thanks in advance for all advises.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
...

    if (!checkMsg()) {
        // return SOAP response
    }

...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SOAPException` cannot be created in the `Filter`. I have to throw `SerlvetException`. If I want to return the `SOAPException`, I have to chain `CXF servlet` and throw it there.